# multithreaded plotting of one subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, matplotlib

I use matplotlib with PySide and want to develop a plotting widget which can be embedded in Qt Gui.

I have to draw ~40 lines with ~100000 points each on one subplot. It can be done, but the performance of panning/zooming is low. Matplotlib uses one thread to handle the plot (the platform on which the app will be running will be 24-threaded), and my question is:

Is there a way of making matplotlib use more than one thread for a single subplot?

I've searched for an answer but all I have found are solutions for drawing many figures and saving them to file, none of them consider handling one plot.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: The way I understand matplotlib: Probably not. I've seen that drawing figures in different processes is possible (e.g. with IPython), but I don't understand how this could work for subplots. Maybe https://pythonhosted.org/guiqwt/ could be an alternative for you.

Comment: @Dietrich Thank you. I already tried pyqtgraph, but I don't want to give up on matplotlib just now.